# I am trying to pass a function in an object, but every time I run the code, it returns "[Function:property]"

Tags: javascript, object, oop

Here is the code

```
var person={
Name:"John",
Age:16,
info () {
    return `I am ${this.Name} and I am ${this.Age} years old.`;
}
};
console.log(person.info);
```

It is returning [Function: info], I want to return the sentence "I am John and I am 16 years old.
Pls make necessary changes...

Comment: This function needs to be _called_.

Comment: You need to invoke the method `info` by adding `()` on the end of its name. Otherwise, [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) will print the function definition itself, rather than executing your instructions written in it and printing the returned value.

Here is what you need: `console.log(person.info());`

Answer (score 1):

Dude... here the only thing you need is to call the function.

```
console.log(person.info());
```

`